# Worksheet_Change code for different sheets with data on one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a dropdown list on 30 sheets where column C is the dropdown list. Based on the selected criteria another value is pasted in column D.

I created code that only works for the sheet where my data is located. I want to execute my code on every spreadsheet in the file based on my ‘Data’ sheet.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Res As Variant
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("c6:c10")) Is Nothing Then
Res = Evaluate("INDEX(b2:b63,MATCH(" & Target.Address & ",A2:a63,0))").
If Not IsError(Res) Then Target.Offset(, 1) = Res
End If
End Sub
```

The code works on the page with my values. What do make the code from the sheet with my data apply to rest of the sheets on the file?

Maybe a `select.worksheet.data` before one of my lines of code or something like that?

Comment: Do you want when a cell is changed **on the sheet where the above event code exists**, or to do the same thing in each cell, **for specific ranges in that specific sheet**?

Comment: @FaneDuru the ranges (b2:b63) and (a2:a63) are my dropdown list and respective weights for each and they are on a separate sheet. The (C6:C10) range is what I want to be affected on every other sheet containing the drop down list. I hope this helps

Comment: this might help ([Microsoft link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/macro-to-loop-through-all-worksheets-in-a-workbook-feef14e3-97cf-00e2-538b-5da40186e2b0))

Comment: You still did not answer my question. What you say does not help. ' (b2:b63) and (a2:a63)` refers **the active sheet**. `Target` is the changed cell in the sheet where the event code exists.  Now, again: do you want that target changing in the sheet where the event code exists **to affect all the sheets**? Or to make changes in **any sheet if a cell is changed in that respective sheet**?

Comment: @FaneDuru sorry I was a little confused. I want the code to affect every sheet outside the active sheet,

Comment: Now, what to be affected? To place **the same `Res` value** in all corresponding cells? I mean, if `Target` address is, let us say, "C7", and `Res` is not an error, should its value be copied **in "D7" of all the other sheets**? If not, in which way to "affect" them? To match the `Target` equivalent in the other sheet (the same address) against  (b2:b63) and (a2:a63) ranges from that respective sheet? You need to describe in details what you need, to have the chance to receive help... Now I will close my laptop. If you clarify the issue, and tomorrow is not too late I will try helping.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the above code to work the same in all the other sheets (**changing something in "C6:C10" range of a specific sheet to bring `Res` in column "D:D" of the respective sheet**), please copy the next code event in `ThisWorkbook` code module (and delete/comment the existing one from the sheet):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim Res As Variant
  If Sh.name <> "MySheet1" Or Sh.name <> "MySheet2" Then 'sheet to be excepted (if the case)
     If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
       If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("c6:c10")) Is Nothing Then
            Res = Evaluate("INDEX(" & Sh.Range("B2:B63").Address(external:=True) & _
                     ",MATCH(" & Target.Address & "," & Sh.Range("A2:A63").Address(external:=True) & ",0))")
       If Not IsError(Res) Then Target.Offset(, 1) = Res
    End If
 End If
End Sub
```

But if there are **synchronized ranges in all sheets** and need to copy **the same returned `Res` from the sheet having the event triggered**, please adapt your code in the next way:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim Res As Variant, ws As Worksheet
 If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("c6:c10")) Is Nothing Then
        Res = Evaluate("INDEX(b2:b63,MATCH(" & Target.Address & ",A2:a63,0))")
    If Not IsError(Res) Then Target.Offset(, 1) = Res
 
    For Each ws In Me.Parent.Worksheets 'place the same Res in the correspondent cell from all sheets
        If ws.name <> "MySheet1" Or ws.name <> "MySheet2" Or ws.name <> Me.name Then  'except some sheets if necessary
           ws.Range(Target.Address).Offset(, 1).value = Res
        End If
    Next
 End If
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing the solution which looks convenient for you.

Comment: @Steamy Didn't you find some time to test the above solution? If tested, didn't it do what you need?